# ¿Why is it necesary to use a table so that controls of form are enable?

Tags: forms, angular-material, angular7

I have observed that to work correctly an input of a form, it must be included in a table, the code attached don't work correctly, Why does it do this??

```
  <form class="formLogin">

    <mat-form-field class="inputForm">

      <input matInput placeholder="EMAIL">

    </mat-form-field>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the setup of your form and include all the required modules, please follow all the documentation about forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

If you're talking about styles, you may have a conflict inside your stylesheets, because following the Material Theming documentation you don't get those kind of issues:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/theming.md

Finally, provide more details about your problem the next time ;)